# Why don't Sephardim read Kohelet on Sukkot?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, sukkot, kohelet

It is the custom among Ashkenazim to read Kohelet on the Shabbat of Chol HaMoed Sukkot.

Is there any reason why Sephardim never took on (or stopped) this custom?

Comment: Masheces tannis(antiochos) used to be read

Comment: @sam megillat taanit and megillat antiochos are two different megillot. It was antiochus that was read (only) by Italian Jewry: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10553-megillat-anteyokos

Comment: There is a theory that the only reason we read Kohelet on Sukkot is because we read the other megillot on the other holidays.  Someone realized that we've got a leftover book (Kohelet) and holiday (Sukkot), and decided to rectify the situation.

Comment: The theory stated above doesn't make any sense because the megillot only became the megillot because they were all read out loud. Before that, they were just other books in ketuvim.

Comment: closely related (dupe?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16705/why-doesnt-chabad-read-ruth-on-shavuot

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10746/5323